# Terminal latex->dvips->ps2pdf malfunction

Tags: ps2pdf

I am using terminal to compile a .tex file created in texshop as it contains the chemnum package. When I run `"latex filename", "dvips filename" , "ps2pdf filename"`I generate an empty pdf, a 20 mb .ps file that when opened in preview contains all the correct output and is effectively a functioning file.

However, I would like to get the ps2pdf function working. What can I do?

.log file here:

```
    Last login: Sat Jun 16 19:05:55 on ttys000
mbp:ESA Report ART$ latex ESAReport
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ESAReport.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/tgbonum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/t1qbk.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemstyle/chemstyle.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemstyle/chemscheme.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psfrag/psfrag.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3dvips.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/varioref.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatrow/floatrow.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemcompounds/chemcompounds.sty))
 (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/chemfig/chemfig.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.de
f
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
ostscript.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/chemfig/chemfig.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/simplekv/simplekv.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.
meta.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemnum/chemnum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemgreek/chemgreek.sty))
(./ESAReport.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dicti
onary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./ESAReport.out) (./ESAReport.out)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-basic-d
ictionary-english.trsl)
Underfull \hbox (badness 1635) in paragraph at lines 51--52
\T1/qbk/m/n/10 pos-sess-ing an ac-tive and in-ac-tive state that
<azoUV.eps> <typesofAB.eps> [1] <tautomer.eps>
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmss/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmss/m/n' instead on input line 79.


Underfull \hbox (badness 2376) in paragraph at lines 90--91
\T1/qbk/m/n/10 eroarene. So called azo-heteroarene pho-to-
[2]
Underfull \hbox (badness 1107) in paragraph at lines 100--101
\T1/qbk/m/n/10 Through a col-lab-o-ra-tion with Joaqu?n Calbo,

Underfull \hbox (badness 1259) in paragraph at lines 100--101
\T1/qbk/m/n/10 com-pu-ta-tional in-ves-ti-ga-tions were ini-ti-ated to

Underfull \hbox (badness 1248) in paragraph at lines 100--101
\T1/qbk/m/n/10 mal half lives (see Fig. [][][][] and Ta-ble
<untitled.eps>
Overfull \hbox (1.90135pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 112--124
 [][] 
<untitled1.eps>
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 146--147

<1802.eps> [3] (./ESAReport.bbl
Underfull \hbox (badness 4913) in paragraph at lines 71--77
\T1/qbk/m/it/10 Ange-wandte Chemie In-ter-na-tional Edi-tion\T1/qbk/m/n/10 ,
) [4] (./ESAReport.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on ESAReport.dvi (4 pages, 55836 bytes).
Transcript written on ESAReport.log.
adityas-mbp:ESA Report ART$ dvips ESAReport
This is dvips(k) 5.998 Copyright 2018 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2018.06.16:1919' -> ESAReport.ps
dvips: Font Arial-BoldMT used in file typesofAB.eps is not in the mapping file.
dvips: Font ArialMT used in file typesofAB.eps is not in the mapping file.
dvips: Font ArialMT used in file tautomer.eps is not in the mapping file.
dvips: Font Arial-BoldMT used in file tautomer.eps is not in the mapping file.
dvips: Font ArialMT used in file untitled1.eps is not in the mapping file.
dvips: Font Arial-BoldMT used in file untitled1.eps is not in the mapping file.
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/dvips/psfrag/psfrag.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/tex-gyre/q-ec.enc>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/dvips/base/color.pro>. 
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qbkri.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qbkb.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfss1000.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy7.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/tex-gyre/qbkr.pfb>[1
<./azoUV.eps><./typesofAB.eps>] [2<./tautomer.eps>] [3<./untitled.eps>
<./untitled1.eps>] [4<./MF1802.eps>] 


 mbp:ESA Report ART$ ps2pdf ESAReport
    Error: /undefinedfilename in (ESAReport)
    Operand stack:

    Execution stack:
       %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
    Dictionary stack:
       --dict:983/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:78/200(L)--
    Current allocation mode is local
    Last OS error: No such file or directory
    GPL Ghostscript 9.23: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
   mbp:ESA Report ART$
```

Comment: `pdflatex` is out of work for you?

Comment: @Sigur pdflatex works for me but if I want chemnum to perform certain actions I need to use terminal as above.

Comment: this answer to another question offers some suggestions about alternative approaches that may be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47965/579

Comment: @barbarabeeton the information in that text is going over my head. What do I have to change in my current workflow?

Comment: the suggestion that i thought interesting, at least worth trying, was to use ps2ps to "normalize" the postscript file before sending it through ps2pdf.  (if i were doing this, i'd make a copy of the ps file and try the ps2ps --> ps2pdf on the copy first.  as that answer note, ps2ps is included in ghostscript tools.  and since you say you're using ps2pdf, which is in the ghostscript collection, i'm assuming you should also have ps2ps.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I ran the following with no success. Still the same issue of a 1 page blank pdf and a 20 mb eps "latex filename", "dvips filename" , "ps2ps filename" "ps2pdf filename"

Comment: this now exceeds my relevant experience.  did either ps2ps or ps2pdf give any warning messages?  (or did dvips?)  if so, knowing what those were would be helpful to someone more familiar with the innards of ps and pdf formats.

Comment: @barbarabeeton If you scroll to the very bottom of the long text above you'll see the warning/errors.

Comment: try this: `ps2pdf ESAReport.ps`.  i don't know whether explicitly specifying the `.ps" will make a difference, but it's worth trying.  (i can't help much more, so a separate chat won't be much use, but maybe someone else will see this and have some better ideas.)

Comment: The dvips run seems to have a problem with the font you are using.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I **definitely** have a file called ESAReport in the folder

Comment: isn't it called `ESAReport.ps` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't see barbara's previous comment asking me to add the .eps ending to get it to work. Doing that works perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the latex processing followed by `dvips` successfully produced a .ps file,
but the attempt to convert the .ps file to pdf failed with this error:

```
ESA Report ART$ ps2pdf ESAReport
Error: /undefinedfilename in (ESAReport)
...
Last OS error: No such file or directory
```

unlike latex and `dvips`, `ps2pdf` makes no assumptions regarding the
extension of a file name, so did not recognize the presence of the .ps
file.

the solution is easy: run `ps2pdf` using the full file name:

```
ps2pdf ESAReport.ps
```

as reported in a comment, this successfully produced the desired pdf output.